# Is it appropriate to ask how to fix a mechanical issue with an electric mulcher on this site?

Tags: discussion

I'm unsure whether a question like this would be appropriate for the home improvement site, so I'm clarifying first. The general nature of my intended question is described in the subject.

I expect electrical issues with tools may be better covered in other SE sites, but fixing mechanical issues with tools doesn't seem to be appropriate for the Gardening SE site, so I'm wondering where best to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit of a fuzzy area as it's not directly covered in either the [can ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [can't ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages. Speaking from familiarity with such questions, they tend to be accepted if they're about repair of electrical *tools* and not small appliances.

I'd give it a go.